# ¿Como puedo citar una cadena depues de haber hecho un strcpy?

Tags: c

Tengo de tarea hacer un programa que pida 2 cadenas, muestre un menú de opciones con las funciones: Comparar, copiar, concatenar, mostrar la longitud, invertir y salir. Pero si se hacen todas las opciones del menú en orden, después de la segunda opción la primera cadena se vuelve la segunda y eso afecta después en las otras opciones que tienen que evaluar la primer cadena ¿Como puedo hacer que después del strcpy la cadena 1 vuelva a ser la misma de antes? Gracias de antemano.

Codigo:

```
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    main()
    {
    system ("color 0B");
    char op,cad1[100],cad2[100];
    int i,j,k;

    printf ("\n\t\t\t\t Funciones de Cadena ");
    printf ("\n\n Ingrese la primer cadena: "); gets (cad1);
    printf (" Ingrese la segunda cadena: "); gets (cad2);
    do {
    printf ("\n\n Menu: "); 
    printf ("\n\n A) Comparar cadenas    D) Mostrar longitud de la                                 
    cadena");
    printf ("\n B) Copiar cadenas      E) Invertir cadena");
    printf ("\n C) Concatenar cadenas  S) Salir");
    printf ("\n\n Escoja una opcion: "); scanf ("%c",&op); printf                 
    ("\n\n\t");

    switch (op) {
        case 'A':
        if (strcmp (cad1,cad2))
        {printf (" %s y %s son cadenas distintas.\n",cad1,cad2);
        fflush (stdin);
        getch ();
        system ("cls");}
    else
        {printf (" %s y %s son cadenas iguales.\n",cad1,cad2);
        fflush (stdin);
        getch (); system ("cls");}
    break;

    case 'B':
    strcpy (cad1,cad2);
    printf (" La cadena 2 copiada en uno es: %s.\n",cad1);
    fflush (stdin); getch(); 
    system ("cls");
    break;

    case 'C':
    strcat (cad1,cad2);
    printf (" Cadena 1 y 2 juntas son: %s.\n",cad1);
    fflush (stdin); getch(); system ("cls");
    break;

    case 'D':
    printf (" La longitud de la cadena 1 es de: %d                 
    caracteres.\n",strlen(cad1));
    fflush (stdin); getch(); system ("cls");
    break;

    case 'E':
    k=strlen(cad1);
    for(i=0,j=k;i<=k;i++,j--)
    /*i es una variable que guarda la cadena en el mismo sentido despues         
    del bucle
    y j es una variable que guarda la inversa*/
    
    printf ("%c",cad1[j]); printf (" es el inverso de %s. ",&cad1);
    if (cad1[i]==cad1[j])
        {printf ("La palabra es un palindromo.\n");
        fflush (stdin); getch(); system ("cls");}
    else 
        printf ("La palabra no es un palindromo.\n");
        fflush (stdin); getch (); system ("cls");
    break;

    case 'S':
    break;

    default: 
    printf ("\a OPCION INCORRECTA INTENTE NUEVAMENTE");
    fflush (stdin);
    break;
    }
    } while (op!='S');
    }
```

Comment: Hola JDelfin, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Sería bueno que colocaras código de un [ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para poder ayudarte. Saludos.

Comment: En vez de usar la cadena original, usa una *cadena auxiliar*. Por ejemplo, en la segunda opción, podemos copiar el contenido de la cadena2 en la cadena_aux y así no sobrescribimos el contenido de la cadena1. Otro ejemplo sería la opción `C`, guardamos el contenido de la cadena1 en cadena_aux y luego concatenamos el contenido de la cadena2 en cadena_aux y así sucesivamente debes hacer en las opciones que puede sobrescribir el contenido de la cadena.

Comment: Por cierto, no uses la función `gets` para leer cadenas, es obsoleta y peligrosa, porque es propensa a que ocurra desbordamiento de búfer. Su reemplazo es `fgets`.

Answer (score 0):

he visto tu problema y la única solución que he encontrado es agregando una función del tipo string como auxiliar, esta servirá para guardar de manera temporal el valor de CAD1 y después de mostrar en pantalla el resultado volviendo a asignarle el valor que debe de tener, pasa en la función de copiar cadenas y en la de concatenar cadenas, también  creo que es importante cambiar la función gets, por fgets, ya que se puede desbordar el tamaño del bufer. aquí te dejo el problema con mi pequeña aportación:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
system ("color 0B");
char op,cad1[100],cad2[100],aux[100];
int i,j,k;
printf ("\n\t\t\t\t Funciones de Cadena ");
printf ("\n\n Ingrese la primer cadena: "); 
gets (cad1);
printf (" Ingrese la segunda cadena: "); 
gets (cad2);
do {
printf ("\n\n Menu: "); 
printf ("\n\n A) Comparar cadenas    D) Mostrar longitud de la  cadena");
printf ("\n B) Copiar cadenas      E) Invertir cadena");
printf ("\n C) Concatenar cadenas  S) Salir");
printf ("\n\n Escoja una opcion: "); 
scanf ("%c",&op); 
printf("\n\n\t");

switch (op) {
    case 'A':
    if (strcmp (cad1,cad2)){
    printf (" %s y %s son cadenas distintas.\n",cad1,cad2);
    fflush (stdin);
    getch ();
    system ("cls");}
else
    {printf (" %s y %s son cadenas iguales.\n",cad1,cad2);
    fflush (stdin);
    getch (); 
    system ("cls");}
break;

case 'B':
//copiado en aux
strcpy(aux,cad1);
strcpy (cad1,cad2);
printf (" La cadena 2 copiada en uno es: %s.\n",cad1);
fflush (stdin);
getch(); 
//se vuelve a asignar
strcpy(cad1,aux);
system ("cls");
break;

case 'C':
//copiar en aux
strcpy(aux,cad1);
strcat (cad1,cad2);
printf (" Cadena 1 y 2 juntas son: %s.\n",cad1);
strcpy(cad1,aux);
fflush (stdin); 
getch(); 
system ("cls");
break;

case 'D':
printf (" La longitud de la cadena 1 es de: %d caracteres.\n",strlen(cad1));
printf("\t La longitud de la cadena 2 es de: %d caracteres. \n",strlen(cad2));
fflush (stdin);
getch(); 
system ("cls");
break;

case 'E':
k=strlen(cad1);
for(i=0,j=k;i<=k;i++,j--)
/*i es una variable que guarda la cadena en el mismo sentido despues         
del bucle
y j es una variable que guarda la inversa*/

printf ("%c",cad1[j]); 
printf (" es el inverso de %s. ",&cad1);
if (cad1[i]==cad1[j])
    {printf ("La palabra es un palindromo.\n");
    fflush (stdin); getch(); system ("cls");}
else 
    printf ("La palabra no es un palindromo.\n");
    fflush (stdin); getch (); system ("cls");
break;

case 'S':
break;

default: 
printf ("\a OPCION INCORRECTA INTENTE NUEVAMENTE");
fflush (stdin);
break;
}
} while (op!='S');
}
```